# Magento 2 Admin Product listing grid showing product details in the wrong language

Tags: admin-panel, magento-2.2.5, language, product-grid, product-listing

I have one store and two store views(English & Arabic). When the admin user browses to product listing grid page in the admin section then by default product name showing in the Arabic language instead of English Language.

FYI below are store view details.

```
1] Arabic store view: store id: 1
2] English store view: store id: 2
```

On the admin product listing grid page, the product name shows in the Arabic Language instead of English Language.

Any idea why I am facing this type of issue in Magento 2.2.5 version??

Any help or guidance highly appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default admin takes values in grid from store id: 0 (admin store) so i think in default you uploaded arabic content.

that is only cause to show arabic content in product grid. and if this is the case i would suggest to do import for default store with english values.

Comment: In the database Product data present for default store(Store Id 0) & Arabic Store(Store Id 1) but still showing arabic data in Admin Catalog Product Grid listing.

Comment: OK so if product data is in english for store 0 and still you have araib content in product grid then i think all should work fine you just need to do redinexing.

1) create new admin user with locale "english"
2) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3) php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 1):

You can go in Admin Dashboard and change the language for the admin section :

Admin Panel -> Go to the System> All Users -> Click admin and navigate to Interface Locale drop-down menu and change the admin language.

Source : https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/change-default-language-in-magento-2.html

Comment: This option is already selected as English still shows product Grid Data in Arabic Language.